# Include an element $id inside ajax query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I edit my product, I want to my categories appear inside the dropdown. Currently it's just

```
-- Select your category --
```

For example, my `$current_category_id = 2`, the dropdown must display the good categories.

How to do that ?

tk

```
<div id="myAjax"><select name="move_to_category_id" id="category_id"><option value="0">-- Select your categorie --</option></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myAjax").on('click', function () {
          var selectedOptionVal = $('#category_id').val();
          $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $categories_ajax; ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
              //data returned from php
              var options_html = '';
              for (var index in data) {
                var category_id = data[index]['id'];
                var category_name = data[index]['text'];
                var selectedString = category_id == selectedOptionVal ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                options_html += '<option value="' + category_id + '"' + selectedString + '>' + category_name + '</option>';
              }
              $('#category_id').html(options_html);
            }
          });
        });
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: You have PHP embedded in JavaScript embedded in HTML embedded that that emits more HTML. Do not do that, it hurts.

Comment: Is it possible ? I am no good in js.

Comment: Is your ajax request works fine after clicking on div ?

Comment: yes, it work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your code says, while clicking on the div you are doing an ajax call based on the selected value in the select box. But there will not be any value while clicking since you are updating the select box after that.

Call the ajax on on ready and populate your drop down box.